# Windows C sockets library which uses iocp/epoll support

Tags: windows, open-source, library, networking, c

Is there a plain C socket library for Windows, but with a simpler API, which uses IOCP under the hood?

I have some legacy C code which I'd like to replace with IOCP, but I would also like to avoid writing the whole thing from scratch, managing buffers, threads, concurrency and all the baggage.

Ideally, it would expose a simpler API which would allow the user to attach a couple of callbacks and forget about it, ideally something like:

```
// call onAccept whenever a new client connects 
callbacks = { .accept = onAccept };
start_listening(TCP, "192.168.0.1", 4200, callbacks);

// call onReceive/onSend when operation finishes
callbacks = { .recv = onReceive, .send = onSend, .close = onClose };
register_callbacks(new_socket, callbacks);

// begin async operation
receive_async(new_socket);
```

I've been able to find mostly C++ libraries, but C sources are mostly examples similar to MSDN, without an actual API.